# restore a factor variable original values

Tags: r, numeric, factors

I have factor variable (Accuracy w/2 levels: "0", "1"). However, I have mistakenly converted to a numeric using the

`Task_df_Acc_Exp$Accuracy <- as.numeric(Task_df_Acc_Exp$Accuracy)`

Now when look up the variable, it looks like that the underlying internal coding  (1, 2) has overwritten the factor original values.

```
Accuracy: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 ...
```

I have tried to converted back to a factor variable, but the variable still the internal coding of (1, 2). Is there anyway I could converted to  factor and restored the original values back?
Do you think that this might affect any subsequent logistic analysis?

**dput**

```
Accuracy = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Try: `Task_df_Acc_Exp$Accuracy <- as.factor(as.numeric(Task_df_Acc_Exp$Accuracy) - 1)`

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply @zx8754 I have just tried that and still gets the (1, 2) instead of the original (0, 1).  > str(Task_df_Acc_Exp$Accuracy)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 ...

Comment: Can you provide example data, please edit your post with `dput(head(Task_df_Acc_Exp))`

Comment: Here you go @zx8754, thanks again for your help. Accuracy = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor")

Comment: Please try `levels(Task_df_Acc_Exp$Accuracy) <- as.numeric(levels(Task_df_Acc_Exp$Accuracy)) - 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, juste decrease levels by one :

```
levels(Task_df_Acc_Exp$Accuracy) <- as.numeric(levels(Task_df_Acc_Exp$Accuracy)) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# decrease by one while it's numeric
Task_df_Acc_Exp$Accuracy = Task_df_Acc_Exp$Accuracy - 1    

# convert back to factor
Task_df_Acc_Exp$Accuracy <- as.factor(Task_df_Acc_Exp$Accuracy)
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: @azizitamimi are you sure it works, your data is factor and numeric operations on factors are not possible from what I know. Try `factor(1)-1`